# toggleclass() is working in a weird way, making an error right after the statement makes it work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am new to this jquery stuff, and had to do a light code to hide and display some ul based on user click. So i created dropdownBlock class which has display: block. The jquery below makes it toggle between display: none and display: block.
So here is my code:

```
jQuery('.flinks span').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).closest('.flinks').find('ul').toggleClass('dropdownBlock');
        //hello;
    });
```

Now the weird thing here is that if I un-comment the hello and deliberately make an error, the code works. Without it the code does work, but the class remains empty. Is it a bug in jquery or am I doing something wrong, or am I totally dumb. Gotta say things like this keeps me up all night.

EDIT
Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="FC2Bg">
        <div id="FC2">
            <div class="flinks">
                <span ><p>Our Extended Services<a>&rsaquo;</a></p></span>
                <p class="ft-wid-det"></p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="f-box f1">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f2">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f3">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f4">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f5">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: not a bug but what is your html structure ?

Comment: I have just included my html, basically the jquery is for mobile devices, to convert this into a single dropdown, and span only appears in mobile width, with the help of css

Comment: it's working ? https://jsfiddle.net/hegqd9zu/3/

Comment: As @Madhawa said, It's working fine tried in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/deepgagan/n3rf79e8/15/

Comment: but in my code the class remains empty in html without hello. Probably there is much bigger problem to the overall structure hence the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you the easiest answer.Do not add any class with display none and display block.
Here is the jsFiddle working https://jsfiddle.net/kL1u830b/
I made some tiny adjustment to your HTML 
Here it is

```
<div id="FC2Bg">
    <div id="FC2">
        <div class="flinks">
            <span ><p>Our Extended Services<a>&rsaquo;</a></p></span>
            <p class="ft-wid-det"></p>
            <ul class="flinks-ul" style="display: none;">
                <li class="f-box f1">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="f-box f2">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="f-box f3">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="f-box f4">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="f-box f5">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just add a class to the 'ul' you want to toggle display.And give it display none by default.
And now the jQuery code :

```
$('.flinks span').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".flinks-ul").toggle();
});
```

jQuery's 'toggle' method does the same.If the specified element has a display of none.It will change it to block.If it has block.It will change it to none.This way it reduces your css styles.When you can use jQuery's own method to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working as it should without your `hello` or with your `hello` (with an error in console with `hello`, albeit doing its job by toggling the class).

A class `dropdownBlock` is getting appended to `ul`s if not there and getting removed if it's there (toggling). So there's no unusual behaviour.

```js
jQuery('.flinks span').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).closest('.flinks').find('ul').toggleClass('dropdownBlock');
       // hello;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="FC2Bg">
        <div id="FC2">
            <div class="flinks">
                <span ><p>Our Extended Services<a>&rsaquo;</a></p></span>
                <p class="ft-wid-det"></p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="f-box f1">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f2">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f3">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f4">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-box f5">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working here: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/9brx3s75/4/

```
$('.flinks span').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.flinks').find('ul').toggleClass('dropdownBlock');
        console.log('dsd')
        //hello;
});
```